# What is the quote command?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Using bash interactive terminal, the output of `quote a` is `'a'` as expected. But quote doesn't work using `bash -c 'quote a'` or in a shell script, giving the error `bash: line 1: quote: command not found`. quote isn't an executable, and I failed to find quote in the bash builtins reference, so where does this command come from?

bashrc:

```
#
# ~/.bashrc
#

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[[ $- != *i* ]] && return

stty -ixon

#source $HOME/.config/xdgrc
#source $HOME/.config/aliasrc

PS1='\[\033[38;2;50;255;50m\]\u\[\033[0m\]@\[\033[38;2;255;70;70m\]\h\[\033[0m\]:\w\[\033[38;2;50;255;50m\]\$\[\033[0m\]> '
```

Comment: What's the output of `type -f quote`? If it works in a terminal you open but not in `bash -c`, then it's probably something added by your `.bashrc` in "interactive" mode

Comment: prints `bash: type: quote: not found`

Comment: Don't think its from bashrc. Quote has the same behavior with those two sources commented out. See edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`quote` is a helper function in `/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion`:

```
# This function shell-quotes the argument
quote()
{
    local quoted=${1//\'/\'\\\'\'}
    printf "'%s'" "$quoted"
}
```

I would not use it since it's only available in interactive shells when completion is enabled.

If you want to escape special characters in a script you can use `${var@Q}` or `printf %q` instead.

```
$ wendys="Where's the beef?"
$ echo "${wendys@Q}"
'Where'\''s the beef?'
$ printf '%q\n' "$wendys"
Where\'s\ the\ beef\?
```